# Android URI from SQLite not displaying in ImageView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-imageview

I have an app which takes a picture from the phone camera and stores the path as TEXT in an sqlite database. I am retrieving the string from the database and parsing it and it is not showing in the ImageView for some reason. Here is all of the relevant code.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_detail);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextBirthdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBirthdate);
        editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAge);
        imageViewStudentImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewStudent);

        _Student_Id = 0;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _Student_Id = intent.getIntExtra("student_Id", 0);
        StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo(this);
        Student student;
        student = repo.getStudentById(_Student_Id);

        editTextBirthdate.setText(student.bd);
        editTextName.setText(student.name);
        editTextEmail.setText(student.email);

//Display Image Here
        if (student.imagepath !=null) imageViewStudentImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(student.imagepath));

        editTextAge.setText(CalculateAge(ConvertDate(student.bd)).toString());

    }
```

URI is file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20150525_124520.jpg

Something interesting is that I cannot find the image in my Gallery app on my phone, but I can find in with my File Browser app. The image does display properly on my phone.

Here is the code that stores the URI

```
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

private void Save(){
        if (!editTextName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

            StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo(this);
            Student student = new Student();

            student.imagepath = fileUri.toString();

            if (!editTextBirthdate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                student.bd = editTextBirthdate.getText().toString();
            } else {
                student.bd = "";
            }

            if (!editTextEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                student.email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            } else {
                student.email = "";
            }

            student.name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            student.student_ID = _Student_Id;

            if (_Student_Id == 0) {
                _Student_Id = repo.insert(student);

                Toast.makeText(this, "New Student Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                repo.update(student);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Student Record updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

private void TakePicture(){
        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Can someone please help me figure out why the ImageView would not display the image?

Edit:

I just discovered this...

```
05-25 13:42:37.954  27938-27938/com.x.xxx W/ImageView﹕ Unable to open content: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20150525_124520.jpg
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20150525_124520.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:650)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:778)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:440)
            at com.xx.xx.StudentDetail.onCreate(StudentDetail.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:650)
            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:778)
            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:440)
            at com.xx.xx.StudentDetail.onCreate(StudentDetail.java:60)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
05-25 13:42:37.954  27938-27938/com.xx.xxI/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20150525_124520.jpg
```

So obviously it is not able to find the folder and or image. What is the best way to handle this? From what I understand, it is not a good idea to store images as BLOBS either.

Comment: You cannot reliably save a `Uri` for later use. In particular, on newer Android devices (Android 4.4+), you may well get a `content://` `Uri` back and have only temporary permissions to read the content represented by that `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for that. I just edited my post with the LOGCAT message that explains the problem. What is the best way to handle referencing images in the SQLite database?

Comment: I have never considered trying to have an app that had references to stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the file name relative to your "MyCameraApp" directory is a better option.
You can get your directory as

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()
            + "/MyCameraApp/";
```

and you can append your file name after the path.
You can open it like this.

```
File file = new File(path) ;
        if (!file.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(activity,R.string.file_deleted,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Intent openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        openIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), file.getMimeType());
        PackageManager manager = activity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(openIntent, 0);
        if (infos.size() > 0) {
            getContext().startActivity(openIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity,R.string.no_application_found_to_open_file,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```